# Datatable.Compute overflow exception

Tags: c#, exception, datatable

I've taken a look at the MSDN but there is no information about a possible exception. However when I use the following code I receive an overflow exception as the value is too large for int32. But the return value according to MDSN is type object. Even when casting the return value to data type LONG it throws an exception.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
new DataTable().Compute("2075144101+100000000", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `DataTable.Compute` is assuming that the input values are `Int32`, so it is parsing to it resulting in an Overflow. You can change this behaviour adding a decimal, so it would be parsed like a `Decimal` instead,like 
this:

```
var a=new DataTable().Compute("2075144101.0+100000000.0", null);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem and providing a solution.

Comment: Is there a way to force the compute to not infer the data types and declare them explicit that doesn't involve manipulating the string to include the zeroes?

Comment: @Narshe I don't think so. In fact, I wouldn't recomend using ´DataTable.Compute´ at all. C# has plenty of arithmetic functions to deal with this in the "right way"

Comment: Sorry C# newbie here. Is there anything that comes with standard libraries to parse simple equations aside from this? Google only gave me third party libraries. Thanks again

Comment: @Narshe unfortunately nothing in standard libraries that I know of. There are several third parties, for example [NReco LambdaParser](https://github.com/nreco/lambdaparser).